# Where to place numeric in this SQL SELECT query

Tags: sql, group-by, average, numeric, partition

I'm wondering where the correct placement for NUMERIC(5,2) in relation to my avg is in my SQL query below:

```
select distinct 
    b.name, avg(c.price) over (partition by b.name) as average_price
from     
    Catalog a 
join 
    books b on (a.book_id = b.id)
join 
    movies c on (a.movie_id = c.id)
where    
    c.price is not null 
    and a.record >= 2
group by 
    b.name, c.price, average_price
```

I have tried what feels like everywhere!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just cast the average:

```sql
select distinct b.name,
       cast(avg(c.price) over (partition by b.name) as numeric(5,2)) as average_price
from ...
```

This assumes that you want the average calculation to proceed using whatever original precision was in the `price` column, and you only want to view the output as `numeric(5,2)`.

Comment: Hmm I get a syntax error near over when I do this

Comment: Try the updated version.